# Problems on sharing bitmap images

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, share

I have used com.nostra13.universalimageloader to load image. Inside the standard ImageAdapter in a ViewPager, there is a share button to share the bitmap. The code is as follows:

## Code:

```
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) 
        {
            ....

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, final Bitmap loadedImage) 
            {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_share = (ImageButton) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
                btn_share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Shining Card";
                        File dir = new File(file_path);
                        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
                        File file = new File(dir, "to share");
                        FileOutputStream fOut;
                        try 
                        {
                            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            loadedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
                            fOut.flush();
                            fOut.close();
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Constants.custom_toast(getActivity(), "Error when sharing", "");
                        }

                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setType("image/*");

                        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Cover Image"));
                    }
                });
            }
```

## Question:

The problem lies on sharing the image.

### Share via whatsapp

Sharing the first image via whatsapp, the image can be shared successfully to others. Continues with sharing second image it also works successfully.

However, if the sharing of the first image is cancelled in whatsapp and return to the app, and then choose another image to share in whatsapp, the preview in whatsapp will remain as the first image, though if ignore it and continue to share whatsapp will actually share the new image. (i.e. there is a preview problem) (using other app to share image perform the same, preview in whatsapp does not go wrong)

### Share via gmail

Sharing the image as attachment via gmail, the image cannot be previewed nor opened.

Comment: There is no question. But what does this have to do with Universal Image Loader? Only your send intent is not behaving as you expected. You are always saving to the same path. Try to use different paths to see if maybe whatsapp 'remembers' your path.

Comment: `(using other app to share image perform the same, preview in whatsapp does not go wrong)` ??? I do not understand what you are trying to tell.